# I lost a folder that I mv'ed from one partition to another (NTFS, windows) partition - Can I retrieve it using Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, ntfs, mv

I have used the `mv` command to move a folder from my Linux partition onto my Windows partition (`mv /home/FOLDER /media/WINPARTITION/User/Me/Music/FOLDER`).

I have read a lot now and understand (I think) that when you do such a thing several things happen:

1) the link to the disk locations where FOLDER was stored on the Linux partition gets deleted (`/home/FOLDER` is gone). It appears really hard to retrieve this data.

2) `FOLDER` did get copied onto the Windows partition (now: `C:\Me\Music\FOLDER`)

3) After booting Windows, Windows restores everything to the last booting situation (i.e. my copied `C:\FOLDER` is gone in Windows as it did not exist at last shut down)

My question is then: If it is so hard to retrieve `FOLDER` at the original location, is there maybe a way to retrieve what Windows had deleted (i.e. `C:\Me\Music\FOLDER`) using a Windows tool?

Thanks a lot for any comments!
Best, 
Tom

Comment: I guess 3) is only true if windows is in hibernation and i write to a shared NTFS partition. The actual sequence of events was: `mv FOLDER /media/WindowsPartition/User/Me/Templates/`. Then, in windows, i discovered that Templates is a weird folder and i cannot access it. so i went back to linux and did `mv /media/WindowsPartition/User/Me/Templates/FOLDER /media/WindowsPartition/User/Me/Music`. Then, after booting into windows, FOLDER was not to be found neither in windows nor in linux. Sorry for missing this description in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, Linux **writing** on NTFS is only supported if the file size doesn't change (or at least doesn't increase).